# Closing a pop-up component and setting state to False after clicking outside the component in the background

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is my `Search.js` component.

```js
class Search extends Component {
    state = {
        doctors: [],
        showTab: false
    }

    openTab = () => {
        this.setState({showTab: true});
        console.log('openTab state', this.state);
    }

    render() {
        let advancedSearch = null;
        if (this.state.showTab===true) {
            advancedSearch = (<AdvancedSearch />)
        }

        return (
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button class="btn btn-md btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" onClick={this.openTab}>Advanced Search</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {advancedSearch}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

And this is my Advanced Search component. No need to look at the code in depth.

```
const advancedSearch = (props) => {
    return (
        <div class="modal inmodal" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content animated bounceInRight">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title"> Advanced Search <i class="fa fa-search"></i> </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="row">
                        {searchFieldsInner.map((field, idx) => (
                            <SearchField
                                key={idx}
                                colWidth={field.colWidth}
                                placeholder={field.placeholder}
                                formControl={field.formControl} />
                        ))}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Search</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
)
```

Basically, when I click on the `advancedSearch`, I want the state to turn to `true`, which I am doing with the `if` statement. However, once the component opens (basically a pop-up view that slides down), and when I click on the background after which the pop-up closes, I want to turn the `showTab` state to `false`. Any suggestions on how to do it?

Comment: is ```advanceSearch``` a full screen element? If not, when ```advanceSearch``` is opened. You can still click on the background to change the state?

Comment: It's not a full screen element. Kind of like a rectangular window which takes a quarter of the screen and that slides across.

Comment: If you want to listen to clicks outside of the popup component, you have two choices. Either create a (transparent or semi-transparent) background element that covers the viewport, and listen for clicks on that. Or you could attach a event listener to the document object itself. It's quite tricky to get every just right for this to work exactly right. There's several libraries that you could use, and if you want to write your own, you could probably find some useful tutorials written on the subject. You have to have a good understanding of the DOM and event propagation.

Answer (score 0):

Advance search should be opened anyway as it needs to be clicked. The things you should control is the content inside advance search. Therefore, the state should be passed into `AdvanceSearch` as props.

```
//Search.js
closeTab = () => {
        this.setState({showTab: false});
        console.log('closeTab state', this.state.showTab);
}


render() {
        return (
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2" onClick={this.closeTab}>
                   //skipped code
                </div>


                <AdvancedSearch isOpen={this.state.showTab} onClick={this.openTab}/> 
            </div>
        )
}
```

```
//advanceSearch.js
const advancedSearch = ({isOpen, open}) => {
    return (
       {isOpen && (
           <div class="modal inmodal" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                //skipped code
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
       )}
)
```

Comment: Thanks. But in addition to that, once advanced search opens and I click on the background, the advanced search component closes. When it closes, I want to change the showTab state back to false. The issue over here is that advanced search comp is the child component.

Comment: Updated my answer. To click the background and change state to ```false```, it is already handled by the ```div``` with ```onClick={this.closeTab}```. As the state is passed down to the ```AdvanceSearch```, it will get the latest state.

Comment: Adding a close tab event handler to the above div means the advanced search component doesn't get rendered. It is basically setting the state to false when I click on the advanced search simply because the event handler is part of the parent div. I tried what you suggested.

Comment: "because the event handler is part of the parent div."  --> the div with the class ```col-md-2``` should be the sibling of ```<AdvanceSearch/>```. Are you putting the ```onClick``` function on the div with class ```row```?